# $elemMatch for last element instead of first

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to find the last element of an array that matches a condition, for example if I had the data from the [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) page:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  students: [
    { name: "john", school: 102, age: 10 },
    { name: "jess", school: 102, age: 11 },
    { name: "jeff", school: 108, age: 15 }
  ]
}
```

I want to find the last element that has `school: 102` in it, in this case I will get `{ name: "jess", school: 102, age: 11 }`.
But `$elemMatch` will return `john` instead.

I feel like there supposed to be an easy way to do it, but couldn't find any solution without using `$unwind` and complex aggregations.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it such a big deal to just get all the documents that contain {school: 102} in the students array, and then find the last instance of 102 in each document as a post process on the client side?

Comment: This is always an option. I was hoping there was a simple mongodb solution. I mean, it's not such an edge case..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to get only students from school `102` and then [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/index.html) with `-1` to get last element from filtered array. To make it as short as possible you can use [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) to define temporary variable, try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            students: {
                $let: {
                    vars: { 
                        filtered: { $filter: { input: "$students", as: "s", cond: { $eq: [ "$$s.school", 102 ] } } } 
                    },
                    in: { $slice: [ "$$filtered", -1 ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: The author has clearly stated that he wants a non aggregation solution.

Comment: @right but there's no "non aggregation solution" for this problem

Comment: True, I thought there was a simple solution I'm missing. Kinda weird there isn't..

Comment: You can always open a ticket here https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa :)